# Running SignalR .Net Client on Linux with Mono - possible?

Tags: .net, mono, signalr

Does anyone have experience running the [SignalR .net client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) on Mono? I am considering this for a process that I need to run cross platform (which needs to connect to a internet hosted SignalR Hub).

Comment: Quick Answer = Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Update: it works with .net 4.0, but not 4.5 since Mono throws a not implemented exception when using some base HTTP Client stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created a sample project with signalr client working under mono framework:

https://github.com/mdymel/mono-signalr-client

I checked it with one of my websites and it works fine.

Comment: Yep I also got my own code to work under the Mono / .NET 4.5 framework. Thanks for posting the example code.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it myself, but since [the SignalR Mono solution](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Mono.sln) file contains the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client40.Samples sample it would really seem like it does.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out Mono [has a tool](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) you can use to scan your assemblies to see if they are compatible with Mono. I did that and here is the results, related to the SignalR .net client:

[image]

So it looks like mono doesn't support some of the async Task stuff. I'll see if there is a way around this...

Comment: This tool seems to be outdated. It checks against mono 2.8. Current version is 3.2.6