# SignalR: Web-hosting on Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, signalr

I am trying to port ASP.NET application on Mono framework. I am using SignalR (v 2.1.0) on ASP.NET hosting. I use the example from ASP.NET official site (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) and can't run it on Mono (v 2.3.0, Ubuntu 14.04, XSP 4), SignalR negotiate request returns 404.
I know that SignalR works on Mono using self-hosting. Are there any posibility to run SignalR on Mono using web-hosting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running SignalR .Net Client on Linux with Mono - possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245994/running-signalr-net-client-on-linux-with-mono-possible) afair you need at least mono v3.x

Comment: @Andreas, no, it is not dublicate. I want to host SignalR server (not client) using ASP.NET hosting.