# SignalR and Websockets on Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-4.5, owin

I've done hours of scouring, trying to figure out why the websockets transport doesn't work through signalr on my c# 4.5 application running on linux via mono 4.0.1.

References in my project:

- `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener`
- `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`

Right now, I'm trying to figure out where the bottleneck is that is preventing websockets from working. The way I understand it, is `SystemWeb` is basically a self running server that utilizes the `Httplistener` to listen on a port for an HTTP connection which then processes them up to `SystemWeb`. Am I getting this part correct?

Can someone point me in the right direction to an open issue, or a bug tracker where this is currently in development? From what I can tell, there are some core functions in `http.sys` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073593/4875631) which are required and present in Windows 8. Are there plans on implementing this in mono? I'd prefer not to get some third party library, and to get this working in `SignalR`.

Comment: i think you will find your answer here...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245994/running-signalr-net-client-on-linux-with-mono-possible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245994/running-signalr-net-client-on-linux-with-mono-possible

Comment: The problem isn't getting SignalR to work, it's getting SignalR websockets working.

Comment: First question that comes to mind is, what version of Microsoft Server are you running on the server hosting your SignalR Server application?

Comment: @JustinRusso Everything should have been noted in my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have made similar investigation about 3 months ago a project with Angular 2 and and Singnalr. I hope, the web socket usage is not essential for your project.

As you can see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24164/signalr-websockets) one of the Xamarin developers stated, it is not working as `System.Web.WebSocket` is not implemented in the [Mono](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Web) and they are not planing to implement it this days.

> I believe there's a lot of work going on with mono's http stack right
>   now and that probably needs to stabilize before we see this particular
>   issue resolved.

I suggest that continue your work with current mono as signalr has fallback for websockets it is not going to be a huge problem and when it is implemented to mono you can simple just update your project. With the current MS's open source policy I believe it is going to be sooner than it supposed to be.

If you need the websocket feature for your project then you should fork the SignalR or find a forked version that uses a 3rd party solution right now [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/) is really popular and has more features.

> I'd encourage anyone interested to fork SignalR and see if they can
>   use one of these xplat websockets implementations to get it working in
>   their own fork.

Update:

Unfortunately, I could not find any fork of SignalR with WebSocketListener but as it has lots of forks it is hard to find.

As far as I know Mono team stop pretty much all implementation and focused on ASP.Net vNext implementation to [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/plans/) as it is [open source](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/roadmap/).

Comment: I am not sure why you refer to Microsoft's open source policy, but Microsoft's own WebSocket support binds to http.sys (Windows only). So their source code won't help Mono out in this case, unless they later put some extra effort here.

Comment: If you're looking for the full bounty, I also need info on the Owin pipeline and a bit more detail on the mono situation. What are my next steps? Has anyone created a fork or done work in this area? I remember seeing some commits to mono, but then reverted. Is this planned soon? SignalR has been hands down the best with fallbacks, and I hate to move towards an entirely new platform to handle websockets.

Comment: ohh i did not answer this for bounty just noticed your question because of it. Unfortunatly don't have any idea about OWIN pipeline. Please check my update in the question for the rest.

Comment: The issue (as already stated) is that Microsoft implemented websockets as an OS feature instead of a protocol. Insane since implementing websockets on any OS and .NET version is easy.. I am not using SignalR, but I would also like to replace the Owin pipeline for websockets with my custom websocket implementation.. Have not found a way yet :(

Out of curiosity, what clients are you using for SignalR? You will only get websockets if you have clients on Win8+, Browsers with websockets and WP8+... AFAIK there are no other clients with websocket support in SignalR...

Comment: @Uffe, I'm using .net clients for desktop integration, and web integration at all using the javascript api. Both are using SSE failbacks which are working, but not ideal.